# Connector guide?

Tags: connector, standard

Are there any guides for connector choices for home electronics projects?  I'm looking for basic stuff that anyone working with specific electronics might know already but others might not, like the voltage range associated with Tamiya connectors or similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partially rely on Wikipedia listings for the IEC standards: [IEC 60320](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) and [IEC 60309](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309), or choose from [full list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_connector_%28disambiguation%29).

But also, rather than specific guides targeted at connectors (which may not to be current or comprehensive), to the best of my knowledge, I would say a common method used is to instead use the spec filters and tables within the connector section of an online catalog/search-engine, e.g., from sellers like Digikey, Mouser, and Farnell. This should get you the most easily comparable, and likely also the most updated, information.

For instance, at Digikey, start with the [Connectors, Interconnects](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects) index, then select a sub-category within that based on what you need.

Once you find a few specific connectors matching your generic spec-filter or category-search, then you can always open up the specific product's datasheet and see if the detailed specs match your requirement.

Comment: I'm less worried about requirements than standards or tradition, but fair enough, always check the data sheet or other resources about the specific connector.